# White Pixel Edges - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a low poly open world game in Unity. This is my first time ever...

**1.** I don't know why but I am getting these weird pixelated edges and white edges, image below (look at tree brown stem, same case with other objects when camera is near them).

[image]

**2.** Can someone help with how I can make this look good on the eyes like other games. **3.** Sometimes I get too dark (almost black) colors for shadows and some times too white reflections from the ground. How can I fix that as well?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the _aliasing artefacts?_  Turn on anti-aliasing (AA) in Unity

Comment: Looks like an anti-aliasing setting, but I'm not sure where you find it in the Unity editor.

Comment: @MickyD Do you know where I can do that?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Antialiasing.html.   
  Also see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html

Comment: That fixed my edge issue but now my shadows are really poor quality even though it says high resolution

Comment: Seems related to the shadows... they seem to be generating as overlay on the image rather than actually underneath objects.

Comment: @Nyerguds it’s called _self-shadowing_

Answer (score -1):

**for Shadows quality**

Project Settings -> Quality

- Shadows Settings (Hard and Soft Shadows) select from drop down option.

Directional Light

- Shadow Type (Soft Shadows)